# How to create form in Symfony 3 that will be displayed on every subpage in header

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to display the same form on every subpage of a website. It would have no sense to pass it to Twig in every action of every Controller. I don't want to create some kind of BaseController that will pass the form to Twig.

I feel that it should be possible with some configuration or service injection but I can't find a suitable method.

I already have form as service `app_bundle.user.form.type.locale`, but where to inject it and how to pass parameter to the form.

EDIT:

`action` attribute of the form would be always current address so it would look like this `<select action="">`

Comment: You can build manualy form in twig and action this form will then be name of controler. In this controller You can get value from Request object.

Comment: But then I would have to pass the value in every action in every constructor. It would be better to inject request to FormType service. What I want to achieve is to have this form service injected in template which is then extended by every other template.

Comment: One action will be enough. For exaple You create SearchBundle and Search Bundle have SearchController with SearchAction (name="search_action"). In Twig You create form and action in this form will be {{search_action}}. I know this is not service but work perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

### Embedding another controller in your base template

One would be to make a controller that will render only the form you need. You would then embed that controller in your base template:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:MyFormController:form')) }}
```

This will work well in your case, and is one of the recommended strategies in the Symfony docs: [Embedding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).

#### Using Twig extension

Another way to do it would be using Twig extensions. You can make a twig extension which will implement a **function** that returns the form.

Something along these lines:

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactory $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('create_my_form', array($this, 'createMyForm')),
        );
    }

    public function createMyForm()
    {
        return $this->formFactory->create(MyFormType::class);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

For instructions on how to wire up your own twig extension you can refer to the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

#### Using blocks

Third way that is also fairly common is using "blocks". These are pretty similar to embedding controllers from the usage perspective. The main difference is that blocks do not issue a subrequest. I don't think it matters in your case, as you need it only in once place, but for websites which have dozens of blocks on a single page, issuing too many subrequests can degrade performance, especially in dev environment.

While you can make your own implementation pretty easy, you can also use an existing bundle: [SonataBlockBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Twig extension which adds a custom Twig function that would initialise a form builder with your custom form type and then returns the created view. After creating the extension you could then call the new Twig function in your base template and render the form as usual.

Note that you will have to configure the form action inside the template explicitly when rendering the form. Otherwise, it would always be sent to the controller that is rendering the current page.

Answer (score -1):

Are you familiar with the `{% extends ... %}` syntax for Twig?

You can read about [inheritance in this link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts).

That would seem the best solution...

Comment: I'm familiar with this. But it doesn't seem to be the solution because I have to pass form to Twig somehow. It is not enough to `extend`/`embed`/`include` some templates, I'm already doing this. Template have to have some form injected somehow.